# MSBuild 16.9 .NET Core 3.1 - OutDir isn't searched for dependencies

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, csproj

I'm trying to use MSBuild in a powershell script to build many projects and solutions in a full application suite.  I set the parameter for OutDir to point to a single binaries directory and from an output perspective that works.

However the documentation states that OutDir is included in AssemblySearchPaths.  But looking at the logs MSBuild is clearly stuck using the hintpath from the csproj file.  I've tried setting AdditionalLibPaths as well with no success.  This appears to be an issue with building from Visual Studio 2019 as well.  My hintpaths point to a common debug directory.  A release build still looks in the debug directory.  This used to work in older versions of Studio in the .NET Framework days.  It worked in older TFS XAML builds setting Output Location to "SingleFolder"

I've also played around with OutDir path ending various quantities of back slashes.  I suspect that this old issue is fixed.

How can I get MSBuild to use an alternate directory for the dependencies?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019

EDIT:
As per the accepted answer, adding OutDir to the AssemblySearchPaths does the trick.  For me, I've created a proj file that I've added to each .NET Core csproj files.  My thought is that when this gets fixed I can remove the tweak in one place.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <AssemblySearchPaths>$(AssemblySearchPaths);$(OutDir)</AssemblySearchPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My hintpaths point to a common debug directory. A release build still
> looks in the debug directory.

The `outdir` is always the output folder which does not distinguish between `Release` and `Debug`. So you have to use `<OutDir>C:\ttt\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>` to distinguish between them.

**Actually**, the system msbuild properties are read earlier than the start of build task. You have to set the properties before the start of build process.

Simply modifying the system properties `outdir` in `csproj` will only take effect during the build process, but the system properties are still read before the build starts, also `AssemblySearchPaths` property read the previous `outdir` property. So you always take the default values before the modification.

You have to use `Directory.Build.props` file, it set the values earlier than msbuild start.

**1)** create a file called `Directory.Build.props` under your project folder.

**2)** add the `outdir` property like these into the file.

```
<Project>

<PropertyGroup>
   <OutDir>C:\ttt\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
</PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**3)** restart VS to enable it.

**However**, I note that it works well in `non-sdk net framework` projects but it does not list under `new-sdk net core` projects.

**non-sdk net framework projects**

[image]

**new-sdk net core projects**

[image]

Not sure it is an issue or the Team has forgotten it. Anyway, [I have reported it to our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/why-AssemblySearchPaths-does-not-list/1373821?entry=myfeedback). You can vote it or add any comments if I did not described it in detail.

**As a workaround**, you could try to set the new value for `AssemblySearchPaths` property.

In order not to lose the original value of `AssemblySearchPaths`, you must add it to `csporj` file rather than `Directory.Build.props` file.

Just add these into `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblySearchPaths>$(AssemblySearchPaths);$(OutDir)</AssemblySearchPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

## **Update 1**

I think it is an issue for net core projects.

What I said before is for **VS IDE build**. Now for **MSBuild Command Line**, it is another situation.

**For non-sdk net framework projects**

When I used `msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -p:outdir=c:\ttt -v:diagnostic`, it shows this:

[image]

Well. It works perfect as we wished.

**However**, when we used the same command line for new-sdk net core projects, it does nothing. So I think it is quite an issue for net core projects.

And you should note that `AdditionalLibPaths` cannot be recognized by `AssemblySearchPaths`.

**When** I used this under :

```
 msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -p:AdditionalLibPaths=c:\ttt -v:diagnostic
```

[image]

[image]

**And** you should note that there is no property for `AdditionalLibPaths` under the list of `AssemblySearchPaths` property. And it also does not work for net core projects.

**In short, it is quite an issue for net core projects no doubt**. I also modify the DC ticket.

**Now for new-sdk net core projects,**

**Since** you used msbuild command line to set properties, so there is no need to use `Directly.Build.props` file. MSbuild command line property assignment is actually the same effect of the file.

**Also**, `AssemblySearchPaths` is not ready-only. You could modify it. And actually, all msbuild properties can be overwritten and that is a flexible feature of MSBuild.

**In summary**, you still have to use `AssemblySearchPaths`.

**Solution**

**Since** **The Team** has some problems with this detail in the net core project, we can use the flexibility of MSbuild to manually modify to get what we want:

**1)** abandon using `Directly.Build.props` file and also keep adding these on the net core csproj file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblySearchPaths>$(AssemblySearchPaths);$(OutDir)</AssemblySearchPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**2)** use the following command line for net core projects:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -p:Outdir=c:\ttt -v:diagnostic
```

[image]

Comment: I understand what your saying about OutDir not looking at release or debug configuration.  I'm calling MSBuild directly from powershell and specifying /p:OutDir=D:\Temp\MSBuild\binDirDev\\ directly as a command line parameter.  I also edited the post to show that I've played around with AdditionalLibPaths NOT AssemblySearchPaths which is read only.

Comment: And I think it is also an issue under Dev Command for VS. And  `AssemblySearchPaths` property can be extended since msbuild is flexible. Please check my detailed updated answer.

Comment: @JohnDyer, `since it is quite an issue so far and we cannot  handle it more here and have to wait the Team's response, so I suggest you could accept this answer to make other community members get a right direction for this issue.` And I will follow the link and tell you any progress. If you want to get what you want in time. you have to use my workaround. And it is kind of you to do that.